# I'm travelling with Emirates to San Francisco. My bag size is 154cm including wheels. The limit is 150cm as per their website. Can this be a problem?

Tags: luggage, emirates

As per [this](https://www.emirates.com/english/before-you-fly/baggage/checked-baggage.aspx), the max size is 150cm. If I include the wheels it comes to 154cm worst case. Can they allow this without penalty?

Comment: I have never seen anyone measuring checked-in baggage dimensions at checkin (unlike carry-on measurements, which are frequent in many places), and I doubt they'd care about 4cm.

Comment: Yeah, I doubt they would mind. I would just not say anything about it.

Answer (score 2):

[Emirates has both weight and piece concept](https://www.emirates.com/english/help/faq/490107/Weight-and-Piece-concept) and, at 154cm, your checked bag is still under the maximum allowed dimensions, although you might have to pay an additional fee (added emphasis mine).

> **Piece concept:**
>
> If you’re travelling to or from Canada, North America, Central America or South America, or you’re travelling from Africa, you’ll need to follow the rules of the piece concept.
>
> This determines how many pieces you can travel with, and the maximum weight and dimensions of your pieces of luggage.
>
> The total dimensions (length + width + height) of each piece must not exceed 150cm (59 inches). ***You’ll be charged an additional fee for any individual items exceeding dimensions of 150cm (59 inches), up to a maximum of 300cm (118 inches).*** If an individual item has total dimensions greater than 300cm (118 inches), it can’t be checked in as baggage and will need to be sent as cargo or freight.